# org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[20] not found

Tags: java, json, parsing

this exception bloc all the next treatments and i don't understand why ?? 
and the json file don't have [20] that elements

```
package com.parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import sun.security.krb5.internal.PAData;

import com.dao.PaysDao;
import com.dao.impl.PaysDaoImpl;
import com.dto.Pays;

public class ParserPays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int c=65;
        System.out.println((char) c);
        try {
            PaysDao payDao = new PaysDaoImpl();
            Pays pa = new Pays();
            for (int j =65 ;j<=91;j++){
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl("http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=" + (char)j));
                JSONArray result = json.getJSONArray("RESULTS");

                for(int i = 1 ; i <= result.length();i++){

                    JSONObject row = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String type =(String) row.get("type");

                    String iso =(String) row.get("c");
                    String city =(String) row.get("city");
                    System.out.println(type);
                    System.out.println(iso);
                    System.out.println(city);
                    if (type.equals("country")){
                        pa.setCodeiso(iso);
                        pa.setIdpays(0);
                        pa.setLibilepays(city);
                        pa.setVilles(null);
                        payDao.saveOrUpdate(pa);
                    }
                    else System.out.println("not a country");

                }
                for(int k = 65 ; k <= 91 ; k++){

                    JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(readUrl("http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query="+(char)j + (char)k));
                    JSONArray result1 = json1.getJSONArray("RESULTS");

                    for(int i = 0 ; i <= result1.length();i++){

                        JSONObject row = result1.getJSONObject(i);
                        String type =(String) row.get("type");

                        String iso =(String) row.get("c");
                        String city =(String) row.get("city");
                        System.out.println(type);
                        System.out.println(iso);
                        System.out.println(city);
                        if (type.equals("country")){
                            pa.setCodeiso(iso);
                            pa.setIdpays(0);
                            pa.setLibilepays(city);
                            pa.setVilles(null);
                            payDao.saveOrUpdate(pa);
                        }
                        else System.out.println("not a country");

                    }
                    for(int h = 65 ; h<= 91 ; h++){
                        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(readUrl("http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=" + (char)j + (char)k + (char)h));
                        JSONArray result2 = json2.getJSONArray("RESULTS");

                        for(int i = 0 ; i <= result2.length();i++){

                            JSONObject row = result2.getJSONObject(i);
                            String type =(String) row.get("type");

                            String iso =(String) row.get("c");
                            String city =(String) row.get("city");
                            System.out.println(type);
                            System.out.println(iso);
                            System.out.println(city);
                            if (type.equals("country")){
                                pa.setCodeiso(iso);
                                pa.setIdpays(0);
                                pa.setLibilepays(city);
                                pa.setVilles(null);
                                payDao.saveOrUpdate(pa);
                            }
                            else System.out.println("not a country");

                        }


                    }
                }

            }



              /*  while (i.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(i.next());
                    // Here I try to take the title element from my slide but it doesn't work!
                    String title = (String) jsonObject.get("title");
                    System.out.println(title);
                }*/
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    private static String readUrl(String string) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            String urlString = string;
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }

}
```

this the console errors :

```
A
        city
        DE
        Aalen
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aarschot
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aalsmeer
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aarle
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aalten
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aalter
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarau
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aartselaar
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aalburg
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aadorf
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarburg
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarwangen
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarberg
        not a country
        city
        GL
        Aasiaat
        not a country
        city
        PF
        AAA
        not a country
        city
        AU
        AAB
        not a country
        city
        EG
        AAC
        not a country
        city
        DE
        Aach
        not a country
        city
        DE
        Aachen
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aalst
        not a country
        city
        DE
        Aalen
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aarschot
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aalsmeer
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aarle
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aalten
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aalter
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarau
        not a country
        city
        BE
        Aartselaar
        not a country
        city
        NL
        Aalburg
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aadorf
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarburg
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarwangen
        not a country
        city
        CH
        Aarberg
        not a country
        city
        GL
        Aasiaat
        not a country
        city
        PF
        AAA
        not a country
        city
        AU
        AAB
        not a country
        city
        EG
        AAC
        not a country
        city
        DE
        Aach
        not a country
        city
        DE
        Aachen
        not a country
        org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[20] not found.
            at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:191)
            at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:287)
            at com.parser.ParserPays.main(ParserPays.java:59)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= result.length();i++)
```

No. Array indices start at 0 and end at len - 1. This should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++)
```